# GUI tool that shows per process IO stats in Linux

Tags: linux, gui, system-monitor

This is similar to [Command line tool on Ubuntu Server to see disk IO stats?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/460/command-line-tool-on-ubuntu-server-to-see-disk-io-stats), only I'm asking for a GUI tool, not a command line tool.

My OS is Debian Wheezy, using LXDE as desktop environment.

Comment: Instead of sending people around collecting information from different pages: would you mind to [edit] your question here, and include all necessary details (specific requirements etc.)? Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for a guide. Moreover, asking for a GUI tool, it might help to state the DE you are using (e.g. LXDE, XFCE), as some of those GUIs might be specific to one of them.

Comment: My DE is LXDE. Other than that, my question looks clear enough to me. By GUI I mean graphical, and not-command line. For example, iotop is command-line.

Comment: While the term "GUI" is clear, there might be some specific requirements you have (e.g. sorting, exporting stats, specific details you need). I just figured what specific details I never thought of when packaging the lastest version of Monitorix (see my answers [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2548/185), [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/468/185#469), and [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1955/185#1957) ;))

Comment: Honestly, even iotop would be good enough, if it didn't require root. Sometimes I see the harddisk's busy-lamp and I want to see which process is doing all the work, but by the time I enter my password the  spike of activity has gone. If only I could assign a shortcut that starts it in terminal without a root password... I guess not requiring root would be a requirement, definitely.

Comment: One more reason I'd recommend you taking a look at Monitorix. Runs as a background process, and you can watch collected stats with your browser – not losing any details (if that would match your request, I can make it an answer with more details and screenshots). OTOH: make an alias to `sudo iotop`, and add your user to `/etc/sudoers` to be permitted running that command w/o entering a password might be an alternative to you, it the only issue is timing because of the password prompt?